# IP address with docker application

Tags: docker, ip, ntp

I try to run a NTP server/client. The application for which I am using NTP is running in a docker.
I am little bit confused, because:

**1. I don't know if I have to configure the /etc/ntp.conf file inside the docker or outside on my machine.**

**2. Which IP address I have to use.** If I use `ifconfig` I get the output below. I dont know if I have to use the IP of the docker or the one of wlp4s0. Also, if I check my IP via https://whatismyipaddress.com/de/meine-ip , I get a totally different IP address which I don't see if I run `ifconfig`. I don't know If its important, but I am using the WLAN of my company.

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:5e:fd:b4:0d  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:5eff:fefd:b40d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1713 (1.7 KB)

enp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:cc:6a:de:50:f6  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4092 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4092 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:689519 (689.5 KB)  TX bytes:689519 (689.5 KB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:b6:d0:1b:90:8b  
          inet addr:10.39.158.200  Bcast:10.39.159.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::dc16:b5ad:2f01:d58a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7821858 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1046710 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10548810679 (10.5 GB)  TX bytes:96754356 (96.7 MB)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Since Docker containers don't have separate notions of time, it doesn't usually make sense to run an NTP daemon in a container; run one as a system process on the host.

Answer (score 1):

You should set-up your NTP server on the underlying host *not* inside a container.

When considering your `ntp.conf` you should ensure you have a *minimum* of 3 upstream servers, and ideally 5 to ensure robust timing. Ideally you should find some low stratum low round trip time servers to use as your upstream providers.

It seems people have reported issues with containers using the wrong time-zone;

If you use an Alpine image then you need to install `tzdata` before hand then set the following inside your docker file;

```
ENV TZ=Europe/London
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

If your using something else other than Alpine then you can still use that same command in your docker file to ensure the correct time zone is set.

A list of valid time-zones can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

As for IP addressing;
`wlp4s0` looks like your physical Ethernet interface for the underlying host - if that is the case then that's the address you should use *provided* all your containers will run on that host, and they themselves can reach that IP address. The reason you see a different IP address when you check on-line is because everything in the output you provided only showed private IP addresses, not public ones. It looks like your public IP is being provided via NAT or similar from your hosting provider/network provider.